# One or many stylesheets in a website? Best practices?

Tags: css, stylesheet

I am a beginner programmer. I am currently building my third site, but really my first relatively large one. I have a simple question about best practices. I find it much easier to have multiple styles sheets each for a separate section of the site rather than a large single one thats crammed with everything. Is this considered acceptable in terms of best practices?

Comment: Of  course, if you separate the styles in differents archives will turn more  easy to you  found where to edit

Answer (score 2):

That depends, there is no clear cut answer.

There are best practices, but they don't exactly translate to something as simple as having only one style sheet, or having several style sheets.

Some things to consider:

- Number of requests. If you have more style sheets you also have more requests to the server, which makes the page slower.
- Combining rules that are used on several pages in one style sheet can reduce the overall load time, eventhough it means that some pages will load and parse rules that are not used on that page.
- Cacheability vs. initial load time. Having few style sheets with a lot of rules means a longer first load time, but once the style sheet is loaded subsequent pages will load faster because the style sheet is in the cache.
- Maintainability. If having more style sheets makes the site easier to maintain, it means a smaler risk for having old unused rules bloating the style sheets.